# Why attribute doesn't update in traitsui on user input

Tags: python, enthought, traitsui

I have a simple program that gets an text input from the user, and displays it on an instrument (Keithley). However, the attribute does not seem to change. That is, when I run the Start method, the output is "Wowee", even if I change Display in a pop-up window. Do I have to make it editable? I didn't think so. I am basically following [Gael Varoquaux's](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/docs/html/tutorials/traits_ui_scientific_app.html) intro to traits.

COntrolPanel.py:

```py
from traits.api import *
from traitsui.api import *

import Keithley3706A_module



class ControlPanel(HasTraits):
    keithley2430settings = Instance(Keithley2430.Keithley2430Settings, ())
    keithley3706Asettings = Instance(Keithley3706A_module.Keithley3706ASettings, ())
    start = Button("Start Measurements")
    clear_3706A_display = Button("Clear K3706A Display")

    k3706A_settings = Keithley3706A_module.Keithley3706ASettings()
    k3706A = Keithley3706A_module.Keithley3706A()
    view = View(Item('start', show_label=False,style='custom' ),
        Item('clear_3706A_display', show_label=False,style='custom' ),
        Item('keithley2430settings',style='custom'),
        Item('keithley3706Asettings',style='simple'))


    def _start_fired(self):
        print "hello %s" % self.k3706A_settings.display
        self.k3706A.message(self.k3706A_settings.display)

    def _clear_3706A_display_fired(self):
        self.k3706A.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ControlPanel().configure_traits()
```

Keithley3706A.py:

```py
from traits.api import *
from traitsui.api import *

import visa
import time

class Keithley3706ASettings(HasTraits):
    display = String("Wowee")

class Keithley3706A(HasTraits):
    def __init__(self):
       self.Keithley3706AUSB = visa.instrument("USB0::0x05E6::0x3706::04019447::INSTR") 

    def message(self,foo):
        s="display.settext('%s')" % foo
        self.Keithley3706AUSB.write("display.clear()")
        self.Keithley3706AUSB.write(s)

    def clear(self):
        self.Keithley3706AUSB.write("display.clear()")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `ControlPanel` class, you have created two different instances of `Keithley3706ASettings`, namely `keithley3706Asettings` and `k3706A_settings`.  If I delete the latter, and replace the use of `k3706A_settings` with `keithley3706Asettings`, it works.  Here's my version (with references to the 2430 device removed, the `k3706A` trait declared as an `Instance` of `Keithley3706A`, and a few other irrelevant UI changes):

```
class ControlPanel(HasTraits):

    keithley3706Asettings = Instance(Keithley3706A_module.Keithley3706ASettings, ())

    k3706A = Instance(Keithley3706A_module.Keithley3706A, ())

    start = Button("Start Measurements")
    clear_3706A_display = Button("Clear K3706A Display")

    view = View(UItem('start'),
                UItem('clear_3706A_display'),
                Item('keithley3706Asettings', style='simple'))

    def _start_fired(self):
        print "hello %s" % self.keithley3706Asettings.display
        self.k3706A.message(self.keithley3706Asettings.display)

    def _clear_3706A_display_fired(self):
        self.k3706A.clear()
```

Comment: Thanks! So why didn't it work? Besides messy, can't have two instances? What is difference between `k3706A = Instance(Keithley3706A_module.Keithley3706A, ())` and `k3706A = Keithley3706A_module.Keithley3706A()`? I can't find a reference for `Instance()`.

Comment: It didn't work because the GUI was changing one instance, but `_start_fired` was using the string from the other instance, which was never changed.  It works without declaring `k3706A` to be an `Instance`, and I don't recall if there are specific problems that can arise by not using `Instance`, but if you're going to use Traits, you might as well make your declaration of the type explicit.  The `Instance` trait type is mentioned in one of the tables of predefined traits here: http://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_user_manual/defining.html#predefined-traits